# Finding the expected value of a card game with replacement

Tags: statistics

A player chooses two cards with replacement from a standard deck. If both of the cards are hearts he wins 25 dollars. If he draws only one heart, he wins 5 dollars. If he draws no hearts he gets no prize. The cost of the game is 4 dollars. Find the expected value of the game for the player.

Comment: What have you tried?  Compute the chance he gets one heart on one draw.  Then compute the chances of two hearts and exactly one heart on two draws.  Add up the winnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $ X $ be the numbers of hearts drawn. There are three outcomes: 1) two hearts drawn $(X=2)$, 2) one heart drawn $(X=1)$, 3) zero hearts drawn $(X=0)$.

What is the probability of each? Since you are drawing with replacement, then $ X \sim Binomial(n=2,p=13/52=1/4) $.

$ P(X=2) = {{2}\choose{2}} \big(\frac{1}{4}\big)^2 \big(1-\frac{1}{4}\big)^{2-2} = \big(\frac{1}{4}\big)^2 $

$ P(X=1) = {{2}\choose{1}} \big(\frac{1}{4}\big)^1 \big(1-\frac{1}{4}\big)^{2-1} = 2 \big(\frac{1}{4}\big) \big(\frac{3}{4}\big) $

$ P(X=0) = {{2}\choose{0}} \big(\frac{1}{4}\big)^0 \big(1-\frac{1}{4}\big)^{2-0} = \big(\frac{3}{4}\big)^2 $

Let $ W(X=i) $ denote the winnings from drawing $ i $ hearts, i.e. $ W(X=2) = 25 $ , $ W(X=1) = 5 $ , $ W(X=0) = 0 $. You can now use this information to compute the expected winnings as follows:

\begin{equation} E(W) = \sum_{i=0}^{i=2} P(X=i) \times W(X=i) \\ 
= P(X=0)W(X=0) + P(X=1)W(X=1) + P(X=2)W(X=2) \\
= \Big(\frac{3}{4}\Big)^2(0) + 2 \Big(\frac{1}{4}\Big) \Big(\frac{3}{4}\Big)(5) + \Big(\frac{1}{4}\Big)^2(25) \end{equation}

The expected earning from playing this game once is simply the expected winnings from one game minus the cost of one game, i.e. $$ E(P) = E(W) - 4 $$

Comment: Why is p= 4/52 should it not be p=1/4 as there are 13 hearts in a deck of 52 cards an we have replacement.

Comment: You are right. I have edited my answer. Thank you!